# How to install pyaudio in pycharm on mac without homebrew

Tags: python, macos, pip, pycharm, pyaudio

I've been trying to use the speech recognition library in a PyCharm virtual environment on Mac, but I need to install PyAudio for it to work.

When I try to install it it gives me this error (this is only the end of the error)

```
 src/pyaudio/device_api.c:9:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
  #include "portaudio.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

The tutorials I have watched have told me to use homebrew but I don't want to install it.
Is there any method to install it without homebrew?

Comment: As an alternative to homebrew you can use MacPorts to install the dependency for pyaudio `sudo port install portaudio`